# Find convex envelope from the non-convex function to prove globally optimal using branch-and-bound

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, convex-hulls

Based on this [reference](https://www.jstor.org/stable/168733) branch-and-bound methods can obtain globally optimal solutions to nonlinear programming problems in which a non-convex function is to be minimized. I have a non-convex function as follows:

$$\min_{\mathbf{x}} F(\mathbf{x}) = \min_{\mathbf{x}} \sum_{i=1}^I \bigg( x_i + (1 - x_i) \Big[\big(\prod_{j=1}^J1-x_j\big)c\Big]\bigg),$$

where $c$ is constant and $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of binary variables. I want to prove that this function can achieve the global optimal solution using branch-and-bound. To realize that, I need to find the convex envelope of the function $F^c(\mathbf{x})$. If I can find that

$F^c(\mathbf{x^*}) = F(\mathbf{x^*})$,

where $\mathbf{x}^*$ is the optimal solution, thus the function can achieve the globally optimal solution. However, I do not understand how to get the convex envelope of my function. Is there any way to prove that the convex envelope of my function has the same result as my non-convex function above when branch-and-bound algorithm is applied?

Comment: Seems be parenthesis error. Should it be after $\min_{\bf x}$ before $\sum$ ?

Comment: No reason to mess around with nonlinear models here, as you can represent that whole thing using linear constraints, by noting that the products are $0$ if any of the involved variables is $1$, and $c$ if they are all $0$. The whole thing is thus easily linearizable by introducing some extra variables and constraints

Comment: @JohanLöfberg So, to get the convex hull from that function, I need to do as you suggest "linearization"?

Comment: No I was not directly answering your question, but more adviced you to solve it using integer linear programming instead as the problem is easily MILP-representable, and thus solvable using branch-and-bound over linear programs (for which there is a plethora of available solvers)

Comment: @JohanLöfberg So is it correct that instead of finding the convex envelope, I need to find the linearization of the non-convex problem? Then, do you know how to prove that using branch-and-bound, my function can attain the globally optimal solution? I have solved the problem using neos solver and Matlab, however, I need mathematical analysis for globally optimal proof.

Comment: No. However, finding the convex envelope for your function is most likely not trivial, I have no idea how to proceed. Also, your question is a bit weird. When solving problems using b&b, you don't start by deriving the convex hull of anything. In fact, deriving the convex hull of a combinatorial object is typically as hard as solving the problem in which the object is used. Instead, you just use some outer approximation and handle the fact that it isn't a convex hull by branching. If you use the convex hull, you basically don't need b&b, roughly speaking.

Comment: I.e., what I am saying is that the easiest way to solve your problem is to perform a standard linearization of the objective, and solve using MILP.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg thanks for the explanation. Thus, to prove the globally optimal solution using the convex hull should be intractable, right? Actually, I want to find the unique feature of my non-convex problem then prove that by using b&b, I can attain the global optimum for my problem. Do you have any suggestion about the way I need to prove?May I prove using the linearization you have mentioned?

Comment: The proof is by construction if you simply perform standard linearization of binary monomials and then use a MILP solver. I have no idea what you mean when you say you want to find the unique feature of your non-convex problem. Once again, it is trivial to linearize and solve globally using a MILP solver.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thanks for your suggestion. I will figure out your idea to realize the proof using linearization. Is it similar to this link? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875627/how-to-solve-binary-nonlinear-programming-problems/2875668#2875668. The proof of b&b which I found from the book (as I mentioned in my question above) is the standard proof, I want to prove using my non-convex problem, not the standard proof but it seems hard to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up to the comments where I argue that a simple way to solve the problem is to write it as a MILP instead.

Introduce a new binary decision variable $q$ representing $\prod_{j=1}^J(1-x_j)$. This can be accomplished with the constraints $q\leq 1-x_j, q\geq \sum_{j=1}^J(1-x_j)-J+1$.

Introduce yet another set of binary variables $s_i$ representing $(1-x_i)q$. This can be modelled with the constraints $s_i \leq q, s_i \leq 1-x_i, s_i \geq q + (1-x_i)-1$.

Your objective is now $\sum_{i=1}^I x_i + cs_i$, which should be minimized subject to the linear constraints above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I will learn using your approach to prove my non-convex problem. After linearizing the problem, I would get MILP problem. Is it true that MILP is always convex?

Comment: No MILPs are not convex, by the very definition since it contains integer variables, and they have exponential worst-case complexity. MILPs are however routinely solved as it is one of the most researched and practically used problem class there is.

Comment: Clearly understand now. Thanks. One more thing, if I have $x$ is positive non-integer, $y$ is binary, thus $r = xy$ has constraints as the link here? https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2010/10/binary-variables-and-quadratic-terms.html

Comment: Yes, just as easy. It is a simple implication which you model using big-M

Comment: Thank you a lot

Comment: Hi Johan...I want to confirm one thing. I have found the MILP problem based on your answers. Then, as you said, my problem is still not convex even though I got MILP. If I solve this MILP using branch-and-bound, is it still valid that my MILP problem will obtain the globally optimal solution? Do you have any reference for this statement?

Comment: Your problem will never be convex as it contains binary variables. That's the whole idea with b&b. You replace the problem with an outer approximation (relax binary variables) and then branch and bound until you've effectively searched through all possible combinations and can conclude you've found the globally optimal solution. The NLP->MILP reformulation is just to get a first step to create an equivalent problem for which there are efficient (in practice, hopefully, as per theory it can never be efficient) global solvers.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. When we relax the binary variables, we will get the lower bound of the solution (if we have minimization). Can I say that every time we branch problems into subproblems (we still have continuous relaxations), we guarantee that globally optimal solution (in this case global lower bound) is achieved?

Comment: The whole idea with branch and bound is to discover globally optimal solutions, so your questions are odd.